What is the History of the books Derech HaChaim and Netiv HaChaim?
BH
Hi, 
In this picture after Shaar Hakollel it says Derech HaChaim is this book by or is was it written lezechut to Yaakov Melisa by Avraham David Lavut? What’s the history behind this? Also is Nervi HaChaim also by Avraham David Lavut?

Did you mean Nesiv where you typed Nervi?

Derech HaChaim is a popular, halakhic work on the siddur authored by R. Yaakov Lorberbaum of Lissa (1760-1832).
R. Avraham David Lavut (1815-1890) realized that many of the rulings of the Derech HaChaim do not align with those of R. Shneur Zalman of Liadi (the Alter Rebbe of Chabad, 1745-1812). Therefore, alongside the Derech HaChaim, R. Lavut chose to print his own work entitled Netiv HaChaim, incorporating the rulings of the Alter Rebbe. He explains all of this in his introduction to the work.
R. Lavut published this work (Derech HaChaim u-Netiv HaChaim) together with another work of his called Sha'ar HaKollel, as an appendix to his version of the Alter Rebbe's siddur called Torah Or. (The version you show here is a modern version containing only Sha'ar HaKollel and Derech HaChaim u-Netiv HaChaim, without the siddur text.)

Derech Chayim was written by a Rabbi Yaakov Loberbaum, better known as the Nesivos Mishpat. He is considered one of the greatest rabbis of a very great generation, and was a prolific author, whose works are foundational to halacha as practiced today. This particular work on the laws of prayer was printed in many siddurim and was the basic handbook for many rabbis of his day on synagogue procedure etc.
Nesiv Hachaim seems to be a commentary on Derech Chayim by Avraham Lavut (not sure of English spelling) for Lubavitch Chassidim to let them know where the Shulchan Aruch Harav differs from the Derech Chayim.
